# API to interact with TFS repository

Tags: api, tfs

I need to pull the names of files along with their extensions from TFS repository.
Are there any APIs to do the same? 
Any alternate method is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [VersionControlServer.GetItems Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.getitems(v=vs.120).aspx) which gets an array of Item objects in the repository.

You can utilize patterns such as `*.cs`, `*.txt` etc and retrieve only files matching those extensions.